# How to get state variable of a class object in java if that object is in an object array?

Tags: java, arrays

I created a Card class:

public class Card {

```
public Card(String f,int v,int s){
    figure = f;
    value = v;
    suit = s;
}

public String figure;int value;int suit;
```

}

and in my main class I used a for loop to initialize multiple cards.

```
    for(int i = 0;i < 52;i++){
        pokerCardsObject[i] = new Card(pokerCards[i],i%13+2,(i+2)/13);
    }
```

The reason I created an array to store all the cards is that I wish to initialize all 52 cards in one loop. If I simply initiate cards like using

```
    Card card = new Card(pokerCards[i],i%13+2,(i+2)/13);
```

then I can't separate them since they all have the same name card. (I feel like I have some misunderstanding here please correct me if I'm wrong.)

But now all the cards are in my object array pokerCardsObject and when I try to get the state variable of one of those cards like this:

```
    System.out.println(pokerCardsObject[34].value);
```

The error states that "Cannot resolve symbol 'value' ".

How should I properly get the value of the cards?

Comment: *I can't separate them since they all have the same name card.*

This is false as the name of the `Card` objects is merely an *identifier*; nothing more.

Comment: Can you access the `figure` of a card from the array?  If so, what do you see is different about how `figure` and `value` are declared?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
public String figure;int value;int suit;
```

This is actually one public field and two package private fields like so:

```
public String figure;
int value;
int suit;
```

You can make the other two fields public, too.

```
public String figure;
public int value;
public int suit;
```

But it is not recommended to make fields public. It is better to use getters (and setter, if needed):

```
private String figure;
private int value;
private int suit;

public String getFigure() {
  return figure;
}

public int getValue() {
  return value;
}

public int getSuit() {
  return suit;
}
```

And then you use the getter instead of the field to get the value:

```
System.out.println(pokerCardsObject[34].getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to access the "value" variable you should better use proper encapsulation + getters and setters in the Card class.

```
private String figure;
private int value;
private int suit;

public Card(String f,int v,int s){
figure = f;
value = v;
suit = s;
}

public String getFigure() { return figure; }
public int getValue() { return value; }
public int getSuit() { return suit; }
```

Then you will be able to call

```
System.out.println(pokerCardsObject[34].getValue());
```

Hope this helped and good luck with your game!